# Babelify require() another JS file from NPM module not defined as main entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

My current setup is a gulp with babelify. This is the basic setup (https://github.com/jerrylow/gulp-start-kit-modular) with this configuration on babelify https://github.com/jerrylow/gulp-start-kit-modular/blob/master/gulpfile.js/tasks/js.js#L28.

I inherited a module from a client from some other contractor. This is a private module hosted on the client's site in a set of packages lets say '@custom' with the module named 'main-module'.

To use the main module you just do

```
require(‘@custom/main-module’);
```

Which is very typical and works. But it has documented that you can use a bunch of other features by doing

```
var moreFeatures = require(‘@custom/main-module/something-else’)();
```

Where something-else.js is a file in '@custom/main-module/src/js/something-else.js' but babelify is not seeing something-else as there's only one main entry point for the main-module.

Comment: I don't understand your scenario. It doesn't sound like an issue with Babel / Babelify. If you were just writing `require()` calls how would `@custom/main-module/something-else` map to `@custom/main-module/src/js/something-else.js`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure either. I'm not familiar with npm module setups and I've been going through its documentation and couldn't figure it out. I think the packages.json is missing something and not sure what that is or if that is the issue. We haven't heard back from the contractor.

Comment: Is there a `browser` property in `package.json`? It sounds like a really unusual setup. Are the files actually in `@custom/main-module/src/js`? Can you just reference those paths directly? If not, and those paths are referenced in `import` declarations perhaps you can use Babel's `resolveModuleSource` option. Or you could try my `pathmodify` plugin.

Comment: @JMM You're right by adding "./something-else": "./src/js/something-else.js", to browser it works.